Add a line after a string in a file using sed
I want to find a string in a file:
example
https://google.com/first/second/45683
and I would like to rewrite it and keep the original line as so:
https://google.com/first/second/45683
https://yahoo.com/third/fourth/45683
I've done a few attempts
sed -r 's@https://google.com/first/second/([a-Z0-9]+)@yahoo.com/third/fourth/\1@' file.txt

output:

yahoo.com/third/fourth/45683

it rewrites but doesn't keep the original line.
Another attempt
sed -r 'a\s@https://google.com/first/second/([a-Z0-9]+)@yahoo.com/third/fourth/\1@' file.txt

output:

https://google.com/first/second/45683
https://google.com/first/second/([a-Z0-9]+)@yahoo.com/third/fourth/1@

it appends both lines but doesn't rewrite the second line.

what are you searching for and what do you want to replace?  are you looking for an exact match on the entire URL or a match on a subsset of he URL (eg, replace all google entries with yahoo)?  If you also had a URL like http://google.com/not/me/123 would you want to change it to http://yahoo.com/not/me/123 or would you leave it alone because it's not an exact match for https://google.com/first/second/45683

What do you want to happen to the other lines from the input that don't match the string in your question?

looks like this:
echo "https://google.com/first/second/45683" \
| sed 's@https://\(.*\)/\(.*\)/\(.*\)@https://\1/\2/\3\nhttps://yahoo.com/third/fourth/\3@g'

I get:
https://google.com/first/second/45683
https://yahoo.com/third/fourth/45683

Enjoy.

You need to tell sed to print out the matching line first, before you modify it with the s// command. Something like this:
sed -E '
  \@https://google.com/first/second/[a-zA-Z0-9]+@ {
    p
    s@https://google.com/first/second/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@https://yahoo.com/third/fourth/\1@
  }
' < data.txt

or, shorter,
sed -E '
  \@https://google.com/first/second/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@ {
    p
    s@@https://yahoo.com/third/fourth/\1@
  }
' < data.txt

This says, "for lines matching the expression https://google.com/first/second/[a-zA-Z0-9]+, first print out the line and then modify using the given s// expression". The modified line gets printed out because that's the default behavior of sed.

Keep it simple (stupid):
$ sed -r 's@https://google.com/first/second/([a-Z0-9]+)@&\nyahoo.com/third/fourth/\1@' file
https://google.com/first/second/45683
yahoo.com/third/fourth/45683

The & shortcut is the whole left matching part.

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():
$ awk '
    { print }
    match($0, "^(https://)google[.]com/first/second/([[:alnum:]]+)", a) {
        print a[1] "yahoo.com/third/fourth/" a[2]
    }
' file
https://google.com/first/second/45683
https://yahoo.com/third/fourth/45683


Have you tried this?
sed -i '/https:\/\/google\.com\/first\/second\/45683/a https://yahoo.com/third/fourth/45683' $YOUR_FILE_PATH

Improved for clarity by escaping the forward slashes:
sed -i '/https:\/\/google\.com\/first\/second\/45683/a https:\/\/yahoo\.com\/third\/fourth\/45683' $YOUR_FILE_PATH

Hope this helps!
